# Copy field from another row with a similar ID plus prefix

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table that contains entries such as this:

```
ID   | LoginCode

1    | 
1011 | abcdefg
2    | 
1012 | wxyz
44   | qwerty
```

I need to copy the logincode from the row with the 101 prefix (eg. 1011, 1012) to the corresponding tow without the prefix (1011 -> 1, 1012 -> 2) while ignoring the tows that have a logincode, but not corresponding ID with a prefix (there is no 10144 entry).

I am able to manually update each line using this query:

```
UPDATE n
SET n.logincode = p.logincode
FROM Clerk n INNER JOIN Clerk P
ON n.id = 1 AND p.id = 1011
```

But there are about 45 ID numbers (total about 90 entries) and I would like to use one query to update them all.

I need to eventually delete the duplicate, prefixed ID rows, and end up with something like this:

```
ID   | LoginCode

1    | abcdefg
2    | wxyz
44   | qwerty
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update Clerk
set LoginCode = coalesce(
    (
        select p.LoginCode from Clerk as p
        where p.ID = cast('101' + cast(Clerk.ID as varchar(10)) as int)
    ),
    LoginCode
)
where LoginCode = ''; -- or is null?
```

If you prefer to use your `inner join` approach, you'd just need to change the join condition:

```
on p.ID = cast('101' + cast(n.ID as varchar(10)) as int)
```

The `where` clause isn't strictly necessary. While the `coalesce()` will prevent you from losing values where no prefix match is found, it's probably wise to restrict your updates to the fewest rows possible.

https://rextester.com/YXF26598

Comment: This was perfect, Thank you so much! I'm now learning about the COALESCE function, thank you for teaching me this as well :)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the multiple edits that probably threw you off.